# Deriving different and incomparable types from int in C++

Tags: c++, typechecking

I know I cannot derive from an int and it is not even necessary, that was just one (non)solution that came to my mind for the problem below.

I have a pair `(foo,bar)` both of which are represented internally by an `int` but I want the `typeof(foo)` to be incomparable with the `typeof(bar)`. This is mainly to prevent me from passing `(foo,bar)` to a function that expects `(bar, foo)`. If I understand it correctly, `typedef` will not do this as it is only an alias.  What would be the easiest way to do this.  If I were to create two different classes for `foo` and `bar` it would be tedious to explicitly provide all the operators supported by `int`. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Do you **really** need **all** operations that can be performed on an int? Hiding some could even be an advantage!

Comment: @Bo Persson What I am dealing with are essentially different sub-sets of ints. Yes, all operations do not make sense for instance `%`. But just want to save myself the tedium.

Comment: It depends on what `foo` and  `bar` is. Making them classes with just `operator+` and `operator-` defined, for example, adds to the abstraction.  It depends on how much abstraction you want or need.  :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As an alternative to writing it yourself, you can use `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` macro available in [`boost/strong_typedef.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/strong_typedef.hpp) header.

```
// macro used to implement a strong typedef.  strong typedef
// guarentees that two types are distinguised even though the
// share the same underlying implementation.  typedef does not create
// a new type.  BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(T, D) creates a new type named D
// that operates as a type T.
```

So, e.g.

```
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(int, foo)
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(int, bar)
```

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus this seems to be the minimum finger typing solution, thanks. I did not expect my question to generate so many active answers and interest. Overwhelmed.

Comment: Interestingly I note that `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` took the approach of having an implicit conversion operator and an explicit constructor (which is sane).

Comment: I learned a lot from the answers and now I find it hard to select one for acceptance. This is the one I will use but @armen and iammilind 's answers made me understand whats going on under the covers, so thank you all. Accepting this to share the spoils somewhat.

Answer (score 10):

```
template <class Tag>
class Int
{
   int i;
   public:
   Int(int i):i(i){}                //implicit conversion from int
   int value() const {return i;}
   operator int() const {return i;} //implicit convertion to int
};

class foo_tag{};
class bar_tag{};

typedef Int<foo_tag> Foo;
typedef Int<bar_tag> Bar;

void f(Foo x, Bar y) {...}
int main()
{
   Foo x = 4;
   Bar y = 10;
   f(x, y); // OK
   f(y, x); // Error
}
```

Comment: Or use `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` ([`boost/strong_typedef.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/strong_typedef.hpp)).

Comment: @Armen: Instead of that, you could write `typedef Int<0> Foo;
typedef Int<1> Bar;` IF the class template parameter is not *type*, rather *integral value*. such as `template<int> class Int{};` If you follow this approach, you don't need `xyz_tag` definitions.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: it may warrant an answer of its own :)

Comment: @Nawaz: Yeah, but in this case it seems quite arbitrary why 0 is for Foo and 1 is for Bar... I don't think there is that much advantage in your suggestion. I personally prefer more typing with tags... but it's just me :)

Comment: The implicit conversions still allow things like `x = x + y`.

Comment: @Armen could you tell me (or point me to a resource that explains) what kind of operator is `operator int` ?  Appreciate your helping out a newbie.

Comment: @Nawaz: But then you run the risk of accidentally definining `typedef Int<1> Cab;` and mixing `Bar` and `Cab` values...

Comment: @san: Sure: [here you go](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr385.htm)

Comment: @san, @Armen: this is a conversion operator, which allows the type to be converted to an `int` when necessary. Unfortunately it's a bad idea, as noted by Bo Persson, because you can then do `Foo x; Bar y = x + 4`... Conversion back to the underlying type should be explicit.

Comment: @Matthieu, @san: If we leave only the explicit `value()` then we'll have to provide all operators such as +, <, etc. by hand which I think isn't the intention of the OP

Comment: @Matthieu, and @Armen: No necessarily. You can write a compile time counter which would give you a different value each time you use it. So `typedef Int<ctcounter> Foo; typedef Int<ctcounter> Bar;` would create two different incompatible types.

Comment: @Armen: yes, you do (and this is what BOOST_TYPEDEF does), however you only write it *once*: for the template class.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, that you cannot do it with `typedef`. However, you can wrap them in a `struct-enum` pair or `int` encapsuled inside `struct`.

```
template<int N>
struct StrongType {  // pseudo code
  int i;
  StrongType () {}
  StrongType (const int i_) : i(i_) {}
  operator int& () { return i; }
  StrongType& operator = (const int i_) {
    i = i_;
    return *this;
  }
  //...
};

typedef StrongType<1> foo;
typedef StrontType<2> bar;
```

**C++0x solution**:

```
enum class foo {};
enum class bar {};
```

Comment: Can you point me to something that I can read to understand this code. I am new to C++

Comment: @iammilind: Note that C++0x had some stringent requirements on `enum`. Notably, assuming that the min value of `foo` is `min-value` and the max value of `foo` is `max-value` then assigning anything out of `[min-value, max-value]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @san, I have just given the basic skeleton for differentiating the types. You have to provide `operator int()`, `operator = ()` etc. to effectively use `foo` as `int`. Let me try editing my answer.